# Django doesn't allow to add record to DB due to not table instance

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have a DB model:

```
class building_list(models.Model):
    building_id = models.CharField(max_length=25, verbose_name="Building ID", unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.building_id

class data(models.Model):   
    oDate = models.DateField()
    building_id = models.ForeignKey( building_list, to_field = "building_id" )
    content = models.CharField(max_length=25, verbose_name="Content")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.content
```

There is no problem to add record via Admin Portal, I can choose building_id  from SELECT list and everything is okay.

But, there is a problem when I am trying to add record via view. Let me show you my code:

```
url(r'^(?P<building_id>[\w-]+)/$', views.test, name='test'),

def test( request, building_id ):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        oDate = request.POST.get('oDate', '')
        content = request.POST.get('content', '')

        row = data( 
            oDate = oDate,
            building_id = building_id,
            content = content 
        )

        return True
```

I see that

```
Cannot assign "u'BrI9'": "data.building_id " must be a "building_list" instance.
```

Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: I see quite a few issues in naming conventions especially the name of classes. I find it difficult to read data() as initialization of an instance. 
Ok, the error message clearly conveying that building_id should be an instance of BuildingList, but the argument is number. So you may have to initialize building list object then go for "data"

Comment: row = data( 
            oDate = oDate,
            building_id =building_list.objects.get(building_id = building_id) ,
            content = content 
        )

Comment: Thanks a lot  Muthuraj , it solved the problem!

Answer (score 1):

You have named your foreign key `building_id`, therefore the id is `building_id_id`. If you want to assign the id instead of the instance, then you have to do:

```
row = data( 
    oDate=oDate,
    building_id_id=building_id,
    content=content,
)
```

The recommended approach in Django would be to name your foreign key `building`.

```
class data(models.Model):   
    oDate = models.DateField()
    building = models.ForeignKey( building_list, to_field = "building_id" )
```

Now the id is `building_id`, and you can do:

```
row = data( 
    oDate=oDate,
    building_id=building_id,
    content=content ,
)
```